# Populate multiple checkbox values by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to populate multiple checkbox values to the same class elements fetched from the database with ajax. Checkbox values are comma-separated like this `(apple, banana, orange)`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var fruits = "banana,apple,orange";
  $(".check").val(fruits);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class"fruits">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="apple">
  <label> Apple</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="orange">
  <label> orange</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="banana">
  <label> Banana</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="mango">
  <label> Mango</label><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var fruits = "banana,apple,orange";
  // Create an array with all the fruits
  var split = fruits.split(',');
  
  // Select each input by the value in this array
  split.forEach(f => {
    // Use the prop checked to check the boxes
    $('input[value="' + f + '"]').prop( "checked", true );
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class"fruits">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="apple">
  <label> Apple</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="orange">
  <label> orange</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="banana">
  <label> Banana</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="mango">
  <label> Mango</label><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` and `includes`:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var fruits = ("banana,apple,orange");
            var array = fruits.split(",");

            $('.check').each(function (i) {
                if (fruits.includes($(this).val()))
                   $(this).prop('checked', true);
            });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class"fruits">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="apple">
  <label> Apple</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="orange">
  <label> orange</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="banana">
  <label> Banana</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="mango">
  <label> Mango</label><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Not wrong. However would be slower then mine solution. You are checking ALL the checkboxes so if you would have 1000 but only 2 checked, this would take much longer than needed. My solution only searches the checkboxes that need to be checked.

Comment: @Wimanicesir I know that but Note that probably it's may impossible you have `1000` checkbox. There is no need to worry about time complexity for constant value! all of them is O(1)